# How do I add the same variable to itself?

Tags: c, variables, addition

I'm trying to add a single variable to itself in C. The problem I have to solve requires me to ask a user how many times X happened to Y. Easy example: Each time someone drinks juice(x), I need to repeatedly add the amount of juice(y).
This is my program so far. Everything I'm trying to do is working as intended to my knowledge, except for the last piece of code I need to figure out which needs to be before the "if" statement. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int a=1;
int b=1;
int i;
float dollars;
float size;
float price;//per ounceprice
float wieght;
int drinks;//times roommate took some juice
int c=0;
int sips;
int total;
int totalowed;
int loopCounter;
int sipstotal;
//.06 per ounce
float juiceTaken;
float juiceTakenCost;
float juiceTakenTotal;
float costperounce=.06;

while(a=b){
    printf("What is the weight (in oz.) of the original container of OJ?\n\n");
    scanf("%f", &wieght);

    printf("What is the cost of the original container of OJ in dollars?\n\n");
    scanf("%f", &dollars);
    price=dollars/wieght;
    printf("%f\n\n", price);

    printf("How many times did your roomate take your juice?\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &drinks);


        for(loopCounter = 0; loopCounter < drinks; loopCounter++){//repeat next line until loop equals amount of times roomate took juice
        printf("How much juice did your roommate take this time?\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &juiceTaken);
            if(juiceTakenTotal>=10)
            printf("Your roomate owes you $%.2f\n", juiceTakenTotal);



}
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you both! You both provided a solution that worked! I found another problem with the code as well which made it not work when I initially tried. In my scanf line, when asking for juiceTaken I note %d instead of %f. I'm scanning for a float value while asking for integer value. lol, I appreciate your help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you never added the amount of juice taken to the total in your code. So just before the last if statement you need to add the line. it will look like:

```
scanf("%d", &juiceTaken);
juiceTakenTotal = juiceTakenTotal + juiceTaken;
        if(juiceTakenTotal>=10)
        printf("Your roomate owes you $%.2f\n", juiceTakenTotal);
```

This will solve your current problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
    scanf("%d", &juiceTaken);
    juiceTakenTotal = juiceTakenTotal + juiceTaken;
            if(juiceTakenTotal>=10)
            price = juiceTakenTotal * price //calculating price
            printf("Your roomate owes you $%.2f\n", juiceTakenTotal);
```

here, you are adding the number of sips to the total number of sips taken.

Comment: I'm trying to do that in the line before the "if" but after the "scanf" for juiceTaken so that juiceTaken is added to itself for a new total.

Comment: The idea is that if the number of "drink" = 10, it will repeatedly ask for juicetaken 10 times. The values of juicetaken must add up the total for each time the user is asked. Then I'll multiply that total amount of juicetaken by the price, and use "if" to check if its greater than or equal to 10.

Comment: do you intend to check the price or the juiceTakenTotal?

Comment: i added the price bit as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct and final code guys. Thanks for all of your help! Genius all over!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int a=1;
int b=1;
float dollars;
float price;//per ounceprice
float wieght;
int drinks;//times roommate took some juice
int loopCounter;
float juiceTaken;
float juiceTakenCost;
float juiceTakenTotal;

while(a=b){
    printf("What is the weight (in oz.) of the original container of OJ?\n\n");
    scanf("%f", &wieght);

    printf("What is the cost of the original container of OJ in dollars?\n\n");
    scanf("%f", &dollars);
    price=dollars/wieght;
    printf("%f\n\n", price);

    printf("How many times did your roomate take your juice?\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &drinks);
    //6 cents per ounce of juice 
    //Insert 2nd loop condition - for loop
        for(loopCounter = 0; loopCounter < drinks; loopCounter++){//repeat next line until loop equals amount of times roomate took juice
        printf("How much juice did your roommate take this time?\n\n");
        scanf("%f", &juiceTaken);
        juiceTakenTotal=juiceTakenTotal + juiceTaken;
        juiceTakenCost=juiceTakenTotal*price;
            if(juiceTakenCost>=10)
            printf("Your roomate owes you $%.2f\n", juiceTakenCost);
            }
    }
return 0;
}
```